# Can I save a conditional in a javascript-object?

Tags: javascript

I'm sorting through an array of objects based on a various conditionals.

I want to count each object for the various conditionals and I'm not sure how I should achivie this. Could I somehow add conditionals to an object:

```
var conversions = [
  {
    name: "Användare",
    conditional: conversion.time_gap > 0,
    count: 0,
  }
]
```

and then loop through and test them:

```
_.each(user.apilog, function(event){
    _.each(conversions, function(conversion){
      if(conversion.conditional){
        conversion.count++;
      }
    })
})
```

This wont work, because time_gap is a variable inside user.apilog and is not defined, but something like this.

Comment: couldn't answer without how _.each is going on...that I could use conversion in conversions ...

Comment: When you create an object property the value can be the result of any JS expression. So yes, you can create a property `conditional` that is the result of evaluating `conversion.time_gap > 0`. If you do it as `{conditional : conversion.time_gap >0}` the value will be set at the time the property is created. If you need it to be dynamically evaluated when the property is read the simplest way is to just make it a method instead: `conditional : function() { return conversion.time_gap > 0; }`.

Comment: why not evaluate `user.apilog.magicproperty` directly in `if`?

Comment: You should be aware of using parentheses when using condition in such things:

    conditional: (conversion.time_gap > 0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a function:

```
var conversions = [
  {
    name: "Användare",
    conditional: function(v) { return (v > 0); },
    count: 0,
  }
]
```

called as:

```
_.each(user.apilog, function(event){
   _.each(conversions, function(conversion){
      if(conversion.conditional(time_gap)){
        conversion.count++;
      }
   })
})
```

Comment: And if arrow syntax can be used, it looks really nice: `conditional: v => v > 0`

Comment: @FelixKling - Is there now a way for JavaScript to support lambda expressions?

Comment: Arrow expressions are adorable, but I'm wary of suggesting them when they're supported almost nowhere.

Comment: @TravisJ: Yes! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @Paul Roub: Transpilers solve that problem. E.g. https://github.com/esnext/esnext . No need to hold back.